# Firebase Cloud Message crash in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently encountered a weird crash, it happens when receive firebase cloud message, not sure the crash is caused by send notification from firebase console when app was in background or not, here is the log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.okhttp.okio.Segment.limit' on a null object reference
   at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.write + 1182(Buffer.java:1182)
   at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.read + 1221(Buffer.java:1221)
   at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read + 55(RealBufferedSource.java:55)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read + 418(HttpConnection.java:418)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.skipAll + 176(Util.java:176)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.discard + 158(Util.java:158)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.close + 435(HttpConnection.java:435)
   at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.close + 374(RealBufferedSource.java:374)
   at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.close + 362(RealBufferedSource.java:362)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzk.zza + 4(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@19.0.1:4)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzi.close + 37(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@19.0.1:37)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zza + 51(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@19.0.1:51)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzc + 59(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@19.0.1:59)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzg.run + 2(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@19.0.1:2)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1113(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 588(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run + 6(:6)
   at java.lang.Thread.run + 818(Thread.java:818)
```

I am not doing any network behaviour during message received, but keep receiving this crash on Fabric and unable to reproduce it myself, this is my firebase dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
```

does anyone having same issue?

-------------------------------------------- Edit code snippet in FirebaseMessagingService

```
/* ------------------------------ Override */

override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage?) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)
    p0?.also { handleFcm(it.data) }
}

/* ------------------------------ Handle FCM by Type */

/**
 * Handle FCM action by type
 *
 * @param dataMap data from FCM
 */
private fun handleFcm(dataMap: Map<String, String>) {
    // Fetch data from FCM data map
    val fcmModel = FcmModel(dataMap)

    // GA
    if (fcmModel.name.isNotEmpty()) {
        GAManager.getInstance().event(
                GAEventCategory.PUSH_NOTIFICATION,
                GAEventAction.RECEIVE,
                fcmModel.name)
    }

    // create intent for PendingIntent
    val intent = FcmUtils.createIntent(this, fcmModel)

    // create channel for Android O
    FcmUtils.createChannelForAndroidO(this, fcmModel)
    buildNotification(intent, fcmModel)
}
```

basically, when receive data, do parsing of each fields and create corresponding intent depends on the fields, then create NotificationCompat.

-------------------------------------------- Edit code snippet in GAManager

```
public class GAManager {

// Instance
private static GAManager GAManager;

// GA tracker
private Tracker tracker;

/* ---------------------------------- Instance & initial */

@NonNull
public static GAManager getInstance() {
    if (GAManager == null) {
        GAManager = new GAManager();
    }
    return GAManager;
}

/**
 * Get tracker id from current market
 *
 * @param context the context
 */
public void initial(@NonNull Context context) {
    // Default GA
    int trackerEnvironment = getGAbyMarketSource();
    tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(trackerEnvironment);

    // Enable Advertising Features.
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
}
```

function `initial` inside `GAManager` called when application `onCreate`, is it the reason?

-------------------------------------------- Issue Found

After did an experiment, found the issue is caused by adding image on firebase cloud message console, it will crash some devices randomly when app stay in background
[image]

Comment: can you share your code where you are using firebase?

Comment: it's likely this NPE is caused by a concurrency problem in your code. If you share your code, I'll review it.

Comment: @NoBody add code snippet

Comment: I also have the same error effecting about ~600 users of my application. This error starts appearing in the Crashlytics from the last 10 days.

Comment: Any updates so far?

Answer (score 0):

You use a singleton class which might initialize in the another thread.
You have to get an instance of it with context of service.

```
GoogleAnalytics mGaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(serviceContext);
```

Comment: Hi, I have add code snippet and description of `GAManager`, but the crash start to happened recently, `GAManager` was added several years ago.

Comment: You have to call initial() inside of your service before sending event.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Firebase library. ( [Issue1](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/927) AND [Issue2](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/709))

Both are currently open. Will have to wait for firebase team to fix it.

Workaround :

Its related to right sizing, width, height and resolution of images, sent from Firebase console.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57918864/1300813) is also useful.