# NullPointerException only on very very few devices after sending Push Notification using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Let me start off by saying, I've seen millions of `NullPointerExceptions`, and I know how to fix them.

But lately (maybe from a month ago?), I've started receiving `NullPointerException` in very very few devices when I send a push notification using FCM.

This is the stack trace I see in Android Vitals of Play Console.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.write (Buffer.java:1182)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.read (Buffer.java:1221)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read (RealBufferedSource.java:65)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read (Http1xStream.java:602)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.skipAll (Util.java:172)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.discard (Util.java:154)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.close (Http1xStream.java:619)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.close (RealBufferedSource.java:421)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.close (RealBufferedSource.java:409)
  at y54.a (Unknown Source:2)
  at zt5.a (30)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.c (6)
  at du5.run (Unknown Source:7)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at qz0.run (Unknown Source:7)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

(I have added deobfuscation files too)

And when I mean very very few devices, to give you the estimate, today the notification was sent to ~9500 users, and the crash occurred on 6 devices. Not a major issue, but considering the fact that I have total 21 crashes in last 7 days, and 6 being the crashes from the notification, it's pretty bad (for ~1K DAU).

I'll add the screenshot from Play Console to show on which devices it is occurring, if it helps to solve the issue:

[image]

Also, if it's of any help, from my observation this occurs when I attach an image along with notification (the latest feature where you can upload an image before sending notification).

So is there anything I can do on my side to avoid this issue? Or is it a bug from firebase side?

Comment: If you think this is a problem withe the FCM client library, please file a bug report with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't know if it's a bug with the library or these particular devices are missing something? Because it's so rare, I'm pretty sure I have a lot of users using Galaxy S9+. I'll try filing a bug report though, I don't have much data regarding this except the stuff above.

Answer (score 2):

So as Doug Stevenson told me to contact Firebase Support, I did and I have an update regarding this bug.

This bug is reported [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/709).

The possible workaround for solving this issue is reducing the image size which is being sent via notification (not confirmed though).

If you have any updates/have been able to produce this bug locally, you can send info that you have on the link mentioned above so that they can investigate more.

**EDIT 0:**

Osjack on that issue said reducing the image size (making it in kb's), and also width to 200px and height proportionally solved the issue for him.

**EDIT 1:**

Seems like they fixed the issue in version 20.1.0 of Cloud Messaging SDK. You can see the release notes [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v20-1-0). So updating the library to 20.1.0 should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Firebase library when you are trying to send an image notification through Firebase console. ( [Issue1](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/927) AND [Issue2](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/709))

Both are currently open. Will have to wait for firebase team to fix it.
We see this hundreds of crashes in Carshlytics but aren't able to reproduce it locally.

**Workaround** :

Its related to right sizing, width, height and resolution of images, sent from Firebase console.